# How to update UI while reading data from InputStream?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uikit, inputstream

I have made a progress view that updates the progress while the data is read from `InputStream`. However, the progress view is not updated when the InputStream reads a large amount of data e.g. a video file. The progress is updated only when the entire file is read. Below is the code that I'm using

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    switch eventCode {
    case .hasBytesAvailable:
        self.readStreamData(inputStream: aStream as! InputStream)
    }
}

func readStream(inputStream : InputStream) {
    var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: 1024)
    let length = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: 1024)
    if length > 0 {
        let temp = Data(bytes: buffer, count: length)
        self.totalBytesRead += temp.count
        sendProgress(totalBytes: Float(self.bytes[receiveCountFiles]), currentBytes: Float(self.totalBytesRead))
        SHFileManager.instance.writeData(fileName: self.currentFileName!, data: temp)
    } else {
        self.streamReceiverProgressDelegate?.didStreamFileReceived(url: SHFileManager.instance.getURL())
    }
}

func sendProgress(totalBytes : Float,currentBytes : Float) {
    let progress =   currentBytes / totalBytes
    print("Progress is \(progress)")
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async(execute: DispatchWorkItem(block: {
        self.streamReceiverProgressDelegate?.onStreamPerFileTransferProgress(progress: progress)
    }))
}
```

**Expected Result**: Data should be read and the progress should be updated on a regular basis while data is being read.

**Actual Result**: Data is being read, but the progress is updated only when the read operation completes. The UI freezes until the read operation completes